# C# new system process no audio is being played

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, audio, process

So I have two applications right, when one completes a log on, it fires the other application up.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            var path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"FilePath\app.exe");
            Process.Start(path);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Here is the code that plays my audio

```
 public void intro()
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
            /* run your code here */
            player = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
            player.URL = "intro.mp3";
            player.controls.play();
        }).Start();
    }
```

However when button 1 is clicked, the application IS run, but there is no sound at all. Not sound when the form is loaded, nor the sound when events are fired. Any help would be appreciated.

Many Thanks!

Comment: So how are we supposed to know why sound isn't playing if you haven't shown us the code that plays the audio file?

Comment: Does the second application start? What kind of sound are you talking about?

Comment: Edited - Its an mp3 file :)

Comment: Not using full path names (c:\foo\bar\baz.mp3) is never not a mistake.  The odds that WMP can find that file are very low.  You lowered the odds by not setting the ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory property.